# Parameters in Java

Tags: java, oop, parameters, parameter-passing

I am a beginner in Java programming and I have encountered a problem within parameters. I am trying to complete some practice questions however I am making a mistake when I am reading the code which I am unsure as to where I am going wrong. Below is the code in discussion and the questions I need to complete-

```
      public class Mystery1 {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
      String whom = "her";
      String who = "him";
      String it = "who";
      String he = "it";
      String she = "whom";

      sentence(he, she, it);
      sentence(she, he, who);
      sentence(who, she, who);
      sentence(it, "stu", "boo");
      sentence(it, whom, who);
      }

      public static void sentence(String she, String who, String whom) {
      System.out.println(who + " and " + whom + " like " + she);
      }
      }
```

Write the output of each of the following calls.

sentence(he, she, it); my answer here is - it and whom like who which has been marked as wrong.

Rather than tell me the answer could someone suggest the steps I need to take so that I can come to correct answer?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Look at how the parameters are used in the `sentence` method - it's not the same order as they are declared

Comment: If you think it is right, what happens when you compile and run the code? Is it the same or different?

Comment: Here’s a clue: The output of `sentence("1", "2", "3")` is `3 and 2 with 1`

Comment: @BillyAtim feel free to read up on [what to do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Rather than tell me the answer could someone suggest the steps I need to take so that I can come to correct answer?

When taking a look at these problems, what you want to do is first check for errors on method implementation.

You want to do this, since your method is obviously working as intended, but close enough to assume it's a programmatic error and not faulty or unexpected behaviour.

1. Are my initialised methods getting the right parameters?
2. Is the implementation of my method causing problems?
3. Are my parameters computed the way intended?

Also, try to use parameter names for your methods that don't confuse you. Setting the name of parameters the same name as certain variables can cause you to assume they are the same, although you they are actually not.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to read about formal parameters and actual parameters.

Your sentence method is declared to have 3 parameters, so whenever you need to call this method you have to pass 3 parameters.
This is the declaration of your method.

```
public static void sentence(String she, String who, String whom)
```

Now when you call this method using this line

```
 sentence(he, she, it)
```

what actually happens is:

the value of he("it") from method call is assigned to variable **she** of method

the value of she("whom") from method call is assigned to variable **who** of method

and the value of it("who") from method call is assigned to variable **whom** of method.

So now when you print this line

```
System.out.println(who + " and " + whom + " like " + she);
```

It will print:  whom and who like it

Comment: Thank you all very much for your comments in particular Shivam you gave me the answer which was what I originally had down a my own answer but it was marked down as wrong. to my knowledge in parameters the order or which the parameters maters so why isit the correct answer which you gave gets printed in that order when "it" is assigned to "she" and "whom" is assigned to "who" and "who" is assigned to "whom". Why doesnt it print it out in this order (it and whom like who) as that would be the logical order? Thank you in advance.

Comment: You didn't want an answer, but rather clues of how to compile an answer yourself.
Feel free to read up on [what you should do when someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).